# Centering a table layout in scroll view

Tags: android, scrollview, android-tablelayout

Currently, I have a scrollview set up like so for when the keyboard pops up:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/home_background"
        >
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:gravity="center" >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:weightSum="2"
                   >
                    <!-- 2 columns -->
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5dip"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_weight="2">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                            android:text="Heading1"
                            />
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                            android:text="Heading2"
                            />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5dip"
                        android:layout_weight="2">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                            android:text="Label1: "
                            />
                        <EditText
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:id="@+id/editLabel1"
                            android:textColor="#C0C0C0"

                            android:layout_width="75dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5dip"
                        android:layout_weight="2">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                            android:text="Label2: "
                            />
                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/editLabel2"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:textColor="#C0C0C0"
                            android:layout_width="75dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5dip"
                        android:layout_weight="2">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                            android:text="Label3: "
                            />
                        <EditText
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:id="@+id/editLabel3"
                            android:textColor="#C0C0C0"

                            android:layout_width="75dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5dip"
                        android:layout_weight="2">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Label4: "
                            />
                        <EditText
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:id="@+id/editLabel4"
                            android:textColor="#C0C0C0"
                            android:layout_width="75dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5dip"
                        android:layout_weight="2">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Label5: "
                            />
                        <EditText
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:id="@+id/editLabel5"
                            android:textColor="#C0C0C0"
                            android:layout_width="75dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5dip"
                        android:layout_weight="2">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Label6: "
                            />
                        <EditText
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:id="@+id/editLabel6"
                            android:textColor="#C0C0C0"
                            android:layout_width="75dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

This centers the linearlayout horizontally and vertically, however the columns are not lined up when the textViews have variable length text. I want to use a tablelayout so that the columns are lined up like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/home_background"
    >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:gravity="center" >
            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
               >
                <!-- 2 columns -->
                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:text="HEading1"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Heading2"
                        />
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Label1: "
                        />
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editLabel1"
                        android:textColor="#C0C0C0"
                        android:layout_width="75dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Label2: "
                        />
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editLabel2"
                        android:textColor="#C0C0C0"
                        android:layout_width="75dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Lable3: "
                        />
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editLAble3"
                        android:textColor="#C0C0C0"
                        android:layout_width="75dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dip">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:text="LAbel4: "
                        />
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editLabel4"
                        android:textColor="#C0C0C0"
                        android:layout_width="75dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Label5: "
                        />
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editLable5"
                        android:textColor="#C0C0C0"
                        android:layout_width="75dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Lablel6: "
                        />
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editLable6"
                        android:textColor="#C0C0C0"
                        android:layout_width="75dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

However, the tablelayout won't center horizontally. Also, in both layouts, the top portion of the layout (Headings and top of first row) is cut off when scrolling with the keyboard up. How can I center the tablelayout both horizontally and vertically and make it so the top portion of the layout is not cut off when scrolling?